# Package external jdbc driver in the application for use in JBoss

Tags: jdbc, jboss

I used to add external JDBC drivers as a core module in JBoss. Is it possible to package it in the EAR, so I don't have to update the server and add modules? If yes, is there any config that needs to be added in `standalone.xml` or `jboss-deployment-structure.xml`?

I have already tried to use the following as module reference when defining my driver in `standalone.xml`, and it did not work:

```xml
<module name="deployment.YourEarOrWar.YourJar.jar" />
```

Answer (score 0):

I have found the solution. You need to add the JAR under your EAR/WAR project and run the server admin console, go to data sources config, and you will find a pre-added JDBC driver (youear.ear_com....).

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).